# CAEmittercell magnification without pixelisation

Tags: objective-c, ios

As I use a CAEmittercell, if I ask for a scale factor, the contents image will be pixelized as it is progressively scaled.
Is there a way that i can use to avoid this, i.e. to show the image smaller at birth and then let it grow to its actual size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `scale` property to a small value—less than 1—should make the cells appear at that scale when they spawn. You can use the `scaleSpeed` property to scale them up to a larger size; as long as the resulting scale doesn’t exceed 1 over the cells’ lifetime, you shouldn’t see pixelation.

Comment: Trivial, obvious... but I missed it. Damn. Thanks.